# for all positive integers $n$, $n$ is even iff $3n^2+8$ is even

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I don't seem to understand how to go about this proof, as it needs to be proven that n will only be even if and only if $3n^2+8$ is. 
i would say that this statement is false, but cannot get a logical reasoning.

Answer (score 3):

1) Let $n$ is even, then $n=2k \Rightarrow 3n^2+8=3\cdot4k^2+8$ is even.

2) Let $3n^2+8$ is even, then $3n^2$ is even, then $n^2$ is even, then $n$ is even

Answer (score 0):

Because if $3n^2+8$ is even then $3n^2$ is even, which says $n^2$ is even, which gives that $n$ is even.

If $n$ is even then $3n^2$ is even and $3n^2+8$ is even.

Comment: Thank you!! by u, do you mean n? or u as an arbitrary value?

Comment: @HitagiHikari I fixed. Thank you! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Taking $3n^2+8$ to the parentheses of $2\implies 2(n^2+4)+n^2=2k$ assume that $n^2$ is odd(also $n$) if we add an odd number with an even number we get an odd number. Let's prove that  an even number added to an odd number results an odd number $$2k+2n+1=2(k+n)+1$$ say $k+n=l$ so the result is $2l+1$ odd! Contradiction! If.$n$ is odd than $n^2$ is odd and $3n^2+8=2(n^2+4)+n^2$ is odd, therefore $n$ should be even...  So if $3n^2+8$ is even $n$ is even too. Let's prove it for the other way around if $n$ is even then assume $n=2k$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, $12k^2+8$ is also even so $3n^2+8$ is even if and only if $n$ is even...

Comment: You really need to improve that answer. I think it's really hard to follow your reasoning (I can't even tell if you're right or wrong).

Comment: Is it that you didn't like The explanation or you really don't understand , ı shall edit alright

Comment: Does my edit explain well how I did the proof (bu contradiction). Is it clear now?

Comment: It's that it's quite hard to follow your reasoning the way you explain it. Perhaps I don't understand/follow it perhaps I do, but in some way I think you're trying to assume that $3n^2+8$ is even and $n^2$ is odd and reach a contradiction. That would mean that the proof is not entirely complete: it wouldn't prove the equivalence both ways (perhaps also the fact that $n^2$ is odd makes $n$ odd is misstated as I'd guess that you need the other way implication).

Comment: I see I misread the question, I haven't shown that also if $n$ is even $3n^2+8$ would be(İ didn't read the only between ifs :()  even. It is not completely legal to say if $n^2$ is odd then $n$ would be odd, it should be the other way around but I used it that way because I thought it was trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Because $3n^2 + 8 = 3n(n+1) + 2(4 - 2n) + n$. Now either $n$ or $n+1$ is even so $3n(n+1)$ is even and $2(4-2n)$ so $3n^2+8$ can be written as a sum of an even number and $n$ making it even iff $n$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

$n$ is even $\iff$  $3n^2 +8$ is even.

1) $\Rightarrow:$

Let $n$ be even: $n=2k$, $k$ is a positive integer.

$3n^2 +8 = 12k^2 +8 = 2(6k^2 +4),$  hence even.

2)$\Leftarrow:$

Let $3n^2 +8 = 2k$, $3n^2 = 2(k-4)$, I.e. $3n^2$ is divisible by $2.$

Theorem of Number Theory:

If $p$, a prime, divides $ab$, then $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divides $b $.

$2$ divides $3n^2$  $\rightarrow$ $2$ divides $n^2.$

Using the theorem again:

$2$ divides $n^2 $, then $2$ divides $n$, I.e. $n$ is even.